# Collision Detection for fast moving game object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I am working on building a basic space shooter game but am having trouble with a trigger collider.

In the game, I have a Bullet prefab that has a Capsule Trigger Collider attached to it and the enemy is right now a basic cube with a box collider attached to it.

When I run the game I start shooting the bullets and the Enemy cube doesn't disappear until after a few shots.

Here is my code for the bullet prefab:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
        if (col.tag == "Enemy") {
            Destroy (col.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

And a screenshot of my Attributes of each game object:

Bullet Prefab:

[image: Bullet Prefab]

And here is the enemy cube:

[image]

Here is a link to a video of what is happening...

https://youtu.be/NjHK6oVP0OQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand that this question may be similar to the one posted in the comments however I did find another solution that may be of some use to people who have this exact issue.

The error was occurring because my "Bullet" prefab was moving so fast that it wasn't able to detect a collision.

***Fix:*** I changed the Collision Detection property of the Bullet prefabs Rigidbody to Continuous Dynamic because it is moving fast. Full reference to Rigidbody Collision Detection Modes the link is below.

[image]

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-collisionDetectionMode.html

The difference between this and the "similar" question's answer posted in the comments is that answer has a lot to do with Raycasting versus very simple colliders (which is more of what I was looking for).

Comment: Definitely a valid in-engine way of addressing this - but it's worth noting in some cases even this mode can miss collisions for small objects at high speeds. If it works for you though, great! Certainly a simpler solution than needing to manually detect imminent collisions.