# Multiplayer collision problem on the client side

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

hello i am building a multiplayer game, and i have a problem with my client receiving information when he gets shot.
i made a script that i attached to the player.

thank you in advance for your help.

```
[Command]
void CmdShoot(){
    GameObject bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate (_bulletPrefab, _canon.position, _canon.rotation);
    bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * _bulletSpeed;
    NetworkServer.Spawn (bullet);
}


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll){
    if (isLocalPlayer) {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "bullet") {
        Debug.Log ("hit");
        isHit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

when i am on the host, everything works perfectly and every time i hit the host, i can see the debug.log in the inspector.
but when i am on the client. the debug.log is not accurate the client only receives the information like 1/3 of the time, sometime it works sometime it doesn't. its like sometime the client doesn't find the gameobject tagged "bullet". Anyone got the same issue or knows how to fix that??

Comment: the OncollisionEnter is on the player script

Comment: Probably related or even a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44266691/7111561

Comment: If it's something like the bullet is moving too fast to handle the collision consider skipping collision and doing a raycasts between last frame's bullet position & new frame bullet position and scan for hits between them.